# Bad configuration of Graph API returns name of function instead token

Tags: facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0, playframework, facebook-oauth

I have Scala (Silhouette + Play) backend app and frontend app written in react.

`http://localhost:9000/authenticate/google` sends request to facebook. Facebook "does" something, and redirects to my front-end app with token in the link.
There is a part of my implementation: `result <- authenticatorService.embed(value, Redirect(s"http://localhost:3000?user-id=${user}"))`

Then I am redirecting to: `http://localhost:3000/?user-id=Rep(Apply%20Function%20user)#_=_`.
The part after`user-id?=` should be token, but it's name of function.
I think there's a mistake in configuration on facebook site.
Does someone used this API in Scala projects?